# How to create views on Google Cloud Sql replica?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I managed to take a dump of my external master and create a replica on cloud sql. So far I'm pretty happy with the process, but during the export I had to ignore views, triggers, etc.

**Now that I've successfully created a slave, how can I re-add the views etc so I can run all my usual scripts against it without changes?** Or do these read-only replicas not support views, triggers, etc? My impression was that it was only the export/import process that didn't support this.

Comment: I was almost certain you must have made a mistake about not being able to import views, but no... [it seems you are correct](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external)... yet as a long-time MySQL DBA, this limitation makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: Instinct tells me you may have to drop the view on the master, using the `IF EXISTS` declaration to avoid breaking replication when the replica tries to drop a nonexistent view, then re-create it on the master and let that replicate.  `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1;` then `CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT ...`.  I hesitate to post that as an answer because it seems so bizarre and unnecessary but you might give it try to see if it's even viable.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I totally agree with you in terms of how bizarre it is, but I like your idea. Let me try that and get back to you. This solution might work views, triggers, and stored procedures since they all must be excluded from dumps (according to [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv)). One question though, why would I need to `DROP VIEW IF EXISTS`? Why not just `CREATE VIEW`? This will fail on the master, but should run successfully on the slave, right?

Comment: In most cases, if a query fails on the master, then it won't be written to the binlog.  [There are exceptions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47166/11651), but in those cases, encountering a *different result* on replica vs master is still a replication error.  When `BINLOG_FORMAT` is set to `ROW` -- as it almost certainly needs to be for safe/sane results in this environment -- triggers/procs/functions/events are not required on the replica, because the master will only write replication events for the rows modified by stored programs, not for the actual invocation of them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Console.
Find the instance you want to create a replica for, and open its more actions menu at the far right of the listing.
Select Create read replica.
If you do not see that choice, the instance is a replica; you cannot create a replica of a replica.

If the instance had backups and binary logging enabled, continue with Step 6. Otherwise, select Automate backups and Enable binary logging, click Continue, and then click Save and restart to restart the instance.
Enabling binary logging causes the instance to be restarted.

In the Create read replica page, update the instance ID, if needed, and any other configuration options required, including name, region, and zone.
Click Create.
Cloud SQL creates a backup, if needed, and creates the replica. You are returned to the instance page for the primary.